# Adding a Prev and Next button to the Accessory view of my UIPicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

In my view controller I have 5 Text Fields, 4 become first responder with keyboard and one with the UIPicker, they are all tagged +1 (0,1,2...)

It just so happens that the textfield that becomes first responder with the Picker is number 3 so its stuck in the middle. In my other fields I have my code set so that the "Next" return button takes me to my next field, but I haven't been able to pull the same off with the picker, code that makes this happen:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textFieldE) {     
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder]; //This of course being the last text field
    } else {
        [(UITextField *)[theTextField.superview viewWithTag:theTextField.tag+1]
         becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The UIPickerView has an accessory view attached to it with a done button, that does in fact `resignFirstResponder` but I need to be able to add a prev and next button to make firstResponder either -1.tag or +1.tag since the picker is stuck in position number 3.

Here is my picker code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == self.textOutlet) {

        self.textOutlet.inputView = _thePicker;
        self.thePicker.hidden = NO;

        UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        [toolbar sizeToFit];

        //to make the done button aligned to the right
        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


        UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(doneClicked:)];


        [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, doneButton, nil]];

        self.textOutlet.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }

    }
```

and of course the action of the "Done" button:

```
-(void)doneClicked:(id) sender
{
    [_textOutlet resignFirstResponder]; //hides the pickerView
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It should work as you want.

```
#define SEGMENTED_CONTROL_TAG 1567 // random

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == self.textOutlet) {

        self.textOutlet.inputView = _thePicker;
        self.thePicker.hidden = NO;

        UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        [toolbar sizeToFit];

        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Previous", @"Next", nil]];
        segmentedControl.tag = theTextField.tag + SEGMENTED_CONTROL_TAG;
        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldContinue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        //to make the done button aligned to the right
        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


        UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(doneClicked:)];


        [toolbar setItems:@[segmentedControl,flexibleSpaceLeft, doneButton]];

        self.textOutlet.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }

}


-(IBAction) textFieldContinue:(UISegmentedControl*)control{
    UITextField *textField;
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:control.tag-1 - SEGMENTED_CONTROL_TAG];
    } else if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:control.tag+1 - SEGMENTED_CONTROL_TAG];
    }
    if(textField) {
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I gave the code a try but the app crashes when I select the text field with the picker.. I replaced `theTextField` with the name of the textfield that has the picker input. I get the following debug log: `2013-07-12 11:34:38.979 calcApp[1519:907] -[UISegmentedControl view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd7bfa0
2013-07-12 11:34:38.981 calcApp[1519:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISegmentedControl view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd7bfa0'
 ` @Vojtech Vrbka

Comment: You have this functions in UIViewController or in your custom UITextField class ?